# How to prevent content change in ContentControl to cater for Animation

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol, wpf-animation

I am writing this application where I want to change a content on a content control with some animation that moves away the old content and brings in the new content but the problem is, OnContentChanged event when I override it usually changes the content.

Is there any way to suspend the base Content Control class from changing the content so I can play my animation?

here is my code:

```
 protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {

        _oldUserControl = oldContent as SlidingBase;
        _oldUserControl.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SlidingBase.ExitAnimationEvent));

        _newUserControl= newContent as SlidingBase;
        _oldUserControl.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SlidingBase.EntryAnimationEvent));

        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, oldContent);

    }
```

where the Sliding Base is my base custom control which have the animation events defined in.

Comment: Show us the code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could launch an animation when you handle the event.
Something like:

```
OnContentChangeEvent()
{
            functionAnimationLauncher();
}

private void functionAnimation()
{
            // you fancy animation goes here
}
```

Maybe a lil bit more of explanation could help me to understand.
Hope it helps!